# Package Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package’ failed to load

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Sql Managment Studio stop working, sending me this message:

```
Package ‘Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package’ failed to load
```

I follow the solution from this page

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2012/01/04/solution-for-package-microsoft-sql-management-studio-package-failed-to-load/

I delete it HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100 key, just like the page says. Now, ssms.exe it's not starting!!! Not even an error message. The article says that, after restart the machine, the registry will be recreated, but I don't have the registry! What am I missing? Now I don't have error message nor Sql Managment Studio!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to help you get back the sql server but for those that haven't deleted "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Sql Server\100\Tools" yet, just rename it to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Sql Server". You don't have to delete the whole thing. That should work but it doesn't fix it for some. If that is the case, check your .net permission setting s.  You might have changed MY_COMPUTER_ZONE code group from full trust to everything. Change it back to full trust. Note that .net permission settings cannot be changed in version 4 and later versions.